# Record two-way audio from phone with laptop

Tags: audio-recording, laptop, phone

I'm trying to connect a phone to a laptop and record two-way the audio. For now I'm using Windows with my own software, and using [VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable) to forward some audio channels.

With my software (simple `Node.js`) I record all incoming / outgoing audio. And it is also possible to listen to a live stream with a browser.

I'm an audio noob, but this is what I tried:

- Split audio
- Connect a headset to the phone
- Record the audio via line in

After a while I had a lot of resound. Also putting the mic and audio out on the same line in is not an option I think.

I have to stick to Windows for the user, but I also tried ofone with Bluetooth. It did not work out of the box, and it looks like it will break sometime. Also googled for Bluetooth HFP (Hands-free Profile) under Windows 10, but it's not supported.

Is there some simple (out of the box) hardware for this situation?
I would like to keep it small and connect it to a laptop.

So on the laptop I want to get:

- Live stream of phone conversation, so
- All audio out from the phone
- The mic channel going into the phone

[image]

Comment: when you say "want to record all audio" please specify. All audio in/out headset?, all audio in/out phone?, all audio which exists in laptop ? (carefull what you wish for)... or something completely else ?

Comment: "my own software"... please specify what this is/does

Comment: Thanks @EdwinvanMierlo . I hope its more clear now.

Comment: Just to be clear, the other person in this situation is consenting to be recorded, correct? Otherwise it's illegal.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure I have a legal setup. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with virtual audio cables, but I am not in a position to test this.

You want to record 3 audio "streams":

- phone audio out L
- phone audio out R
- headset audio out mic

With your virtual audio cable, you need to split these audio "streams" and route them to your custom software for recording/streaming.

How exactly in detail you do this, you need to figure out, as it is impossible to see on what interfaces this comes in, and therefor impossible to detail here in an answer.

Good Luck.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Will try it again, but I think I also need some hardware to capture  ..